# Reshaping arrays in Time-Series RNN Beginners Block

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

New to python and deep learning. I was trying to build an RNN with some data and I don't know where am I going wrong.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline



raw = pd.read_excel('Online Retail.xlsx',index_col='InvoiceDate')
sales = raw.drop(['InvoiceNo','StockCode','Country','Description'],axis=1)
sales.head()
sales.index = pd.to_datetime(sales.index)
sales.info()

train_set = sales.head(50000)
test_set = sales.tail(41909)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()


training =  np.nan_to_num(train_set)
testing = np.nan_to_num(test_set)

train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(training)
test_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(testing)


def next_batch(training_data,batch_size,steps):
  rand_start = np.random.randint(0,len(training_data)-steps)
  y_batch = 
  np.array(training_data[rand_start:rand_start+steps+1].reshape(26,steps+1))
  return 
  y_batch[:,:-1].reshape(-1,steps,1),y_batch[:,1:].reshape(-1,steps,1)

  import tensorflow as tf


  num_inputs = 1
  num_time_steps = 10
  num_neurons = 100
  num_outputs = 1
  learning_rate = 0.03
  num_train_iterations = 4000
  batch_size = 1

  X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,num_time_steps,num_inputs])
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,num_time_steps,num_outputs])

  cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(
 tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=num_neurons,activation=tf.nn.relu),output_size=num_outputs) 

 outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

 loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y)) # MSE
 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
 train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
 saver = tf.train.Saver()
 with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto()) as sess:
     sess.run(init)

     for iteration in range(num_train_iterations):

        X_batch, y_batch = next_batch(train_scaled,batch_size,num_time_steps)
        sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})

        if iteration % 100 == 0:

            mse = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            print(iteration, "\tMSE:", mse)

    # Save Model for Later
    saver.save(sess, "./ex_time_series_model")
```

The output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-f2f7c66a33df> in <module>()
      4         for iteration in range(num_train_iterations):
      5 
----> 6             X_batch, y_batch = next_batch(train_scaled,batch_size,num_time_steps)
      7             sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
      8 

<ipython-input-26-f673a469c67d> in next_batch(training_data, batch_size, steps)
      1 def next_batch(training_data,batch_size,steps):
      2     rand_start = np.random.randint(0,len(training_data)-steps)
----> 3     y_batch = np.array(training_data[rand_start:rand_start+steps+1].reshape(26,steps+1))
      4     return y_batch[:,:-1].reshape(-1,steps,1),y_batch[:,1:].reshape(-1,steps,1)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 33 into shape (26,11)

In [ ]:
```

Comment: Narrowing this down to a minimal reproducible example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the number `26` came from, but it doesn't match with your data dimensions. After you dropped four columns, the `training_data` array is `(50000, 3)`, of which you take `(11, 3)` batches. This array obviously can't reshape to `(26, 11)`.

What you probably meant is this (in `next_batch` function):

```
y_batch = np.array(training_data[rand_start:rand_start+steps+1].reshape(3,steps+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you trying to reshape a tensor with size `33` into a tensor with size `26x11`, which you can't. You should reshape a tensor with size `286` into `26x11`.

Try to debug the `next_batch` function by printing the `y_batch` shape in each step using `print (y_batch.get_shape())` and check it, if it has shape `286`.

I didn't catch this point, why you fetch each batch randomly? why didn't you read input data normally?

It would be good if you fix the indents when you posting your code, it is hard to track.